# How does grill/broil mode in a convection oven work?

Tags: oven

I'm looking to buy a [new oven](https://www.iona.com.sg/oven/iona-18l-convection-rotisserie-oven-with-fermentation-function).

However, it does not have grill mode (broil, in US English) listed as one of the functions while other ovens may have grill mode advertised.

That being said, if I want to grill something in the oven I've linked, can it still be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "grilling". The term is used differently in different places, so it would help to understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: It usually mean a top element - also called broiler.   You need to define what grill means to you.

Comment: @Catija If it's an oven, it's the UK meaning - edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something approaching it, but it's less efficient.

Basically, you want to place the food close to the top element, and crank the heat all the way up.  An extra pan on one of the lower racks of the oven will help to deflect some of the heat coming in from the lower element.

For non-countertop models, you'll also want to leave the door propped open -- if you don't, the oven will heat up and cycle the elements off.

That being said ... the model of oven you linked to mentions "Independent upper and lower element temperature setting" ... so it might be possible to set the upper element on high while the lower one is off or at least on low.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looking at the zoom on hover pictures, and the text in the features. 
You can see 3 dials and individual on/off switches probably for the elements.   The fan probably activates when the lower element is on.

Top dial - Controls top element for either single use (broil/grill), combination with Lower element for baking (eg bread, pizza)
Middle dial - Controls lower element 
Lower dial - Controls timer

You can try downloading the instructions and see what is written regarding the modes of operation.  Else contact the retailer/manufacturer or check for reviews on the oven.